# Angular - Object is possibly 'null' .ts(2531)?

Tags: angular

In my Angular code I got error **Object is possibly 'null' .ts(2531)**

**here is my code**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   currentNumber = '0';
   firstOperand = null;
   operator = null;
   waitForSecondNumber = false;

  private doCalculation(op: any , secondOp: number){
      switch (op){
      case '+':
      return this.firstOperand += secondOp; 
      case '-': 
      return this.firstOperand -= secondOp; 
      case '*': 
      return this.firstOperand *= secondOp; 
      case '/': 
      return this.firstOperand /= secondOp; 
      case '=':
      return secondOp;
  }
 }
}
```

I got the error at **doCalculation()** method in all return statement **this.firstOperand += secondOp;**

Thanks in advance

Comment: which variable is possibly null?

Comment: If you do something `null += 1` in JavaScript there will be a runtime error, because the left side of the expression is invalid. The TypeScript compiler warns you about this. So I don't really understand the point of your question.

Answer (score 0):

`this.firstOperand` is initialized as `null` therefore you are doing something like this:
`retuen null += 10;`

you should initialize  `firstOperand` to `0` instead of null;

also it's strongly adviced to add a `default` in your switch ;)